# Hibernate envers hibernate_sequence cannot be found in schema

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Im trying to use hibernate envers..

I have tables annotated with @Audited, but problem occurs with hibernate_sequence..

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS custom_schema.hibernate_sequence START 1 INCREMENT 1;
```

So Im using custom_schema and obviously problem is

> ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist

So Im asking if it is possible to somehow tell hibernate in which schema this sequence is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved by creating own revisionentity

```
@RevisionEntity
@Entity
@Table(name = "revinfo", schema = "custom_schema")
class RevInfo (
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @RevisionNumber
    var id: Long? = null,

    @RevisionTimestamp
    var timestamp: Long = 0
)
```